# -llibrary how to determine and locate object-file-name

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am reading through a `Makefile` where I saw `-lz -ldl -ldw` linker option being passed to `gcc`.
This library is not installed on my Linux system so the compilation is failing.
My question is how do I determine the library to install from such linker options in general. The above linker options are just examples, but I would like to know how to determine the libraries in such scenario in general.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Is it about how to determine that `-lz` maps to `libz.so`? Well, then literally, adding `lib` at beginning and `.so` or `.a` at ending (liker will try both, if not restricted manually).

Answer (score 1):

I think as @keltar stated, your best guess is to remove -l from the library to be linked, add `lib` instead and search for this as package name on your system. 
To take an example, if you have `-lz`, you can do

```
apt-cache search libz
```

or

```
yum search libz
```

to see if there are obvious installation candidates. If this doesn't help, you can look for the file name constructed by the same principle mentioned already. 
In the case of `-ldl` you would come up with `libdl.so` and then you can do:

```
apt-file search libdl.so
```

which gives a number of hits.

Does this help?